# Converting an image to base64 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, canvas, base64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get image data in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

Can someone show me a way that I can use a java script function that takes a string path to an image (could be local or on another domain) and returns the base64 encoding of it. But from all the other scripts I found I couldn't use the result in an img src tag, the img didn't load for some reason. the return value needs to look exactly like the .toDataURL(); method.

Thanks